# SASS fails my build using Grunt on Windows 2008 Server

Tags: sass, gruntjs, bamboo

Running this on Windows Server 2008 R2

Getting error when trying to compile SASS from a Bamboo task. All my other tasks in my Gruntfile work fine, it's just the SASS that is giving this error:

> Warning: Unable to write "dist/css/style.min.css" file (Error code: EPERM). Use --force to continue

Bamboo is running as Administrator and all the related pieces were all installed as this user as well.

Here is what I have in my Gruntfile

```
sass: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      style: 'compressed'
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'css',
      src: ['**/style.scss'],
      dest: 'dist/css/',
      ext: '.min.css'
    }]
  }
}
```

If I delete my dist/css directory from Windows explorer and run from the command line, it works, but no amount of messing around like that get's it to work from within Bamboo. I'm working around this now by just having my local compiled css in my repository, but really want this as part of our build process.

If anyone could suggest some things to try, I would appreciate it. I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was a PATH issue. When we installed Ruby (for SASS) it wrote to the local user PATH. This is fine, except that Bamboo didn't see this change until we rebooted the server. This however created another issue for us. Now that there was something in the local user PATH, Bamboo stopped using the system PATH and started using the local users PATH and everything else stopped working! To fix this we just added to path to Ruby to the system PATH and all was good in the world again.